# Change Square Brackets to Round Brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

Would like to change Square Brackets to Round Brackets (parentheses) on the lowercase text using regex Find/Replace in Notepad++

But not affect the Square Brackets where the first letter is capitol A-Z

The brackets could span across two lines. Tried to show example but forum makes it a single line. Had to use double CR's

Change this:

```
[indistinct chatter]

[indistinct chatter

across the room]

[Maya sighs]

[George yelling

from across the street]
```

To this:

```
(indistinct chatter)

(indistinct chatter

across the room)

[Maya sighs]

[George yelling

from across the street]
```

Tried some variations to find this: [Previously on Hit & Run]

```
\[([a-z][\U\s]*)\]
\[([A-Za-z][A-Za-z\s]*)\]
\[([a-z][a-zA-Z\s]*)\]
\[([a-z][A-ZA-Z\s]*)\]
\[([A-Z][A-Za-z\s]*)\] .... thought this was gonna do it
```

This text was found:  `[Ron groans]`

This was not found:   `[Previously on Hit & Run]`  its the `&`, how to include special chars ?

How does this find lowercase when capitols are used in expression?
Find:       `\[([^A-Z].+?)\]`

Answer (score 1):

```
// must be all lower case:
find:
\[([a-z\s]*)\] 

//or specifically only the first letter lowercase, allowing subsequent characters as uppercase:
\[([a-z][A-Za-z\s]*)\] 

Replace with:
 ($1)
```

Comment: Steve Tomlin@ I noticed my answer was exact copy of your answer, you only forgot to tell that `Match-Case ` must be checked,

Comment: @Steve Tomlin and Chris Doyle ..... Thanks a BUNCH .... all 3 methods worked great. Hopefully one day the LIGHT will come on ... lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to find things starting with a bracket but not followed by an uppercase character then match any char including new line "not greedy" until you find closing barcket. I have set the ". matches new line" and the "match case" flags

```
\[([^A-Z].+?)\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
\[([a-z][\S\s]+?)\]
```

**Replace with:**

```
($1)
```

**Demo:**

- https://regex101.com/r/NBCuOV/1

**In:**

```
[indistinct chatter]

[indistinct chatter

across the room]

[Maya sighs]

[George yelling

from across the street]
```

**Out:**

```
(indistinct chatter)

(indistinct chatter

across the room)

[Maya sighs]

[George yelling

from across the street]
```